# Android emulator not load full website

Tags: android, webview, emulation

I am trying to create apk file for my website i did that but my website contains image slider.In android emulator it opens my website but not fully loaded it doesn't show image slider and menus. It shows only header of my website i don't know how to fix this.

Can anyone help me to fix this

Comment: Good question @KVK please follow my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator or any mobile device will load your website properly if it is mobile responsive.Moreover if you want to use menu in your app then you should use Sliding Menu or Navigation Drawer.